# Can i use a Tally marks fonts in UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel

does Apple support usage of tally fonts ?
i'm using this tally from here :http://www.subtangent.com/maths/resources.php

with this coding:

```
  UILabel *subtitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 2, 185, 30)];
    [subtitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [subtitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Tally_Regular.ttf" size:19.0]];
   [subtitle setText:@"5"];
    [subtitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [fLikeThis    addSubview:subtitle];
```

However it does't work as expected, not sure why as i also entered the font name in "Fonts provided by application".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  "Fonts provided by application" you need to add file name e.g. your ttf file not font name 
modify your info plist as follow:-

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>yourfontfilename.ttf </string>
</array>
```

and use font name in label :-

```
[subtitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontname" size:19.0]];//This is your font name not your font file name.You can get font name by opening it with fontbook in mac.
```

if still not working then may be something wrong in ttf file.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply....yea not working...i guess is something wrong with the ttf file