# How to load font family in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to use separate font styles for iphone.
So, need to load font family.
How to load font family in iphone.

Can anyone please..

Comment: </sigh> http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+custom+font

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484937/can-i-use-a-tally-marks-fonts-in-uilabel/8485009#8485009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. drag and drop your customFontName.ttf file to your project
2. Goto projectname-info.plist in supporting files. Add a key Fonts provided
   by application -> add new item -> give value customFontName.ttf

[image]

3. use it where ever you want as,

> myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"customFontName" size:15.0];

Answer (score 1):

Try this [link](http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/using-custom-fonts-in-your-ios-application/).you shall get through